# Failed to solve the motion: most likely there are no good keyframes

Tags: keyframes, error, tracking

I chose my camera tracking points, I locked them, but when I go to Solve Camera Motion, I received this message in red "Failed to solve the motion: most likely there are no good keyframes".
How do I fix that?

Comment: How many tracking markers do you have? Are the camera settings appropriately set up for your camera?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error to and the solution was that I had 6 tracks you need 8.